# Remover todos os elementos do Environment que contenham números e letras maiúsculas

Tags: r

Considere os objetos:

```
vectorA<-1:10
vectorU<-1:10
vector<-1:10
vector1<-1:10
vector86<-1:10
```

- Como remover os objetos que contenham números?
- Como remover os objetos que contenham letras maiúsculas?

Meu objetivo é fazer isto de uma só vez, de tal forma que reste apenas`vector`. Não quero ter de digitar, por exemplo:

```
rm(vector1,vector86...)
```

Quero usar algo como: `[0-9]` e `[A-Z]` dentro da função `rm`.

Além disso, como ficaria a função para uma `list`? Segue `dput`da mesma para auxiliar a resposta:

```
mylist=structure(list(dataset1 = structure(list(var1 = 
c(52.8239523619413, 
67.412983905524, 85.6350479647517, 69.0797958150506, 23.8283388130367, 
95.553572345525, 29.0164476074278, 71.0307511687279, 40.3978266194463
), var2 = c(29.2814019694924, 61.8766243383288, 27.239320538938, 
27.597702536732, 61.7392177134752, 79.012787565589, 57.9802662879229, 
80.5304721556604, 64.3874954432249), var3 = c(28.0727723427117, 
60.635687764734, 28.839645255357, 21.5680585056543, 41.4972599223256, 
78.5253136977553, 71.1393622308969, 43.5780669748783, 50.4048792645335
), var4 = c(63.3389138430357, 39.6925644949079, 64.7707579657435, 
49.8857426457107, 24.3227748572826, 20.8205243013799, 
34.4325823150575, 
24.2039945721626, 28.1429144367576), var5 = c(68.8740702904761, 
55.5163130350411, 24.4956089183688, 35.9698024578393, 41.842991374433, 
93.4637849777937, 78.2090006582439, 63.6315332911909, 35.8201904967427
), var6 = c(49.4833218678832, 79.0594268217683, 84.8702448047698, 
89.154454190284, 45.2969283424318, 95.3247463144362, 58.4594663605094, 
97.3974690772593, 81.7770860157907), kmeans = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = 
"factor")), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans"), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 24L, 25L), class = "data.frame"), 
mydata = structure(list(var1 = c(68.8994040898979, 86.4890068769455, 
41.4491515234113, 48.7125792913139, 67.0896042510867, 
89.0794235467911, 
41.5327339619398, 78.3874392323196, 47.4415177851915, 83.976521063596, 
23.752948474139, 20.1965479925275, 65.0721608288586, 88.8870289362967, 
74.9182807281613, 84.6756487898529, 99.3809685111046, 
80.1436454802752, 
97.8404737263918), var2 = c(32.7941456995904, 64.6668173931539, 
34.7624584287405, 77.6456462778151, 73.1857040151954, 
28.4563537873328, 
86.6737443953753, 92.1690583974123, 96.1259284429252, 
95.3986377082765, 
54.7287909500301, 61.9130505435169, 92.1239553764462, 
97.6163926720619, 
91.1119207553566, 59.7223405726254, 56.271854378283, 63.5032017342746, 
97.2438823990524), var3 = c(96.9139205291867, 32.3409661464393, 
94.5406094565988, 52.3079419881105, 92.548458352685, 82.7145664207637, 
83.1966380216181, 53.0209177173674, 56.4625365659595, 
83.9760917425156, 
92.0599205233157, 55.0897601060569, 40.1735444366932, 
29.7791076265275, 
88.4056675434113, 71.2447142973542, 46.5862010978162, 
44.6803763508797, 
81.6879714652896), var4 = c(70.233196914196, 50.9632669016719, 
68.2954710535705, 77.7710892260075, 98.3270382508636, 59.908417519182, 
92.4725500866771, 31.0966997593641, 78.1473434716463, 
68.3402911759913, 
62.4164910800755, 83.3351655490696, 59.4744057022035, 
75.3354255855083, 
82.4973624758422, 69.706082995981, 86.8536845035851, 78.9299669303, 
49.516792036593), var5 = c(68.4397785365582, 86.5204527787864, 
24.5654080621898, 89.3807902187109, 64.756205175072, 85.9483086690307, 
25.5898364260793, 78.8896332494915, 87.7399998344481, 
22.7459753118455, 
42.6951446570456, 49.3495168350637, 41.639910582453, 98.5095219127834, 
43.6992948688567, 82.0324843563139, 97.1282077953219, 
67.0289828069508, 
83.0017600394785), var6 = c(35.3501682728529, 31.1327565461397, 
21.9722577184439, 44.7750159911811, 41.9370178319514, 
53.7735476344824, 
35.3551966138184, 38.252913877368, 34.6147643961012, 32.9839759506285, 
28.1436816416681, 24.9134236015379, 26.697716023773, 31.1821212992072, 
29.7940192557871, 68.7213623709977, 72.2950306721032, 
45.6320049799979, 
38.598245754838), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans"), row.names = c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 30L), class = "data.frame"), dataset2 = 
structure(list(
    var1 = c(24.4858060218394, 38.8159691542387), var2 = 
c(92.535456828773, 
    92.1455484442413), var3 = c(23.7727256864309, 39.6465750969946
    ), var4 = c(81.2065978161991, 62.8835928440094), var5 = 
c(47.5475750491023, 
    45.1348656974733), var6 = c(90.111320503056, 79.97005013749
    ), kmeans = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans"), row.names = c(11L, 
28L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("dataset1", "mydata", 
"dataset2"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
remover <- ls() %>% keep(~str_detect(.x, "[:digit:]|[:upper:]"))
rm(list = remover)
```

A função `ls()` lista todas as variaveis do ambiente. Em seguida apenas fazemos um filtro para manter na lista aquelas que possuem algum dígito ou letra maiúscula.

Usamos a função `rm` com o argumento `list` para poder passar strings com o nome das variáveis.

Vale lembrar que modificar o ambiente global desta forma não é uma boa prática. Provalmente seu código ficaria melhor se usasse uma lista nomeada.

**No caso da lista**

Com a lista eu faria algo assim:

```
discard(mylist, str_detect(names(mylist), "[:digit:]"))
```

Ou ainda mais sucinto:

```
mylist %>% discard(str_detect(names(.), "[:digit:]"))
```

Comment: Daniel, como ficaria a solução com `purrr::keep` para uma lista? Tente executar aqui só para eliminar os objetos que contenham números, mas não consegui. Veja: `remove<-mylist%>%keep(~str_detect(.x,'[[:digit:]]'))`. Isso gera uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: `Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
In addition: Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing`

Comment: A lista está nomeada e contém três elementos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado, Daniel. Funciona perfeitamente. Vou estudar melhor estas notações no `purrr`.

Answer (score 7):

Dá pra fazer isso com o `R` base também, através do seguinte código:

```
ls()
[1] "vector"   "vector1"  "vector86" "vectorA"  "vectorU"
```

A função `ls()` lista todas as variáveis do ambiente e seu resultado é um vetor. Portanto, ele possui índices que podem ser acessados. Queremos uma maneira de chegar nos índices 2, 3, 4 e 5, que são os que possuem pelo menos um dígito ou pelo menos uma letra maiúscula. Para isso, usaremos a expressão regular `[[:digit:]]|[[:upper:]]`, que significa justamente encontrar

- um dígito `:digit:`
- ou `|`
- uma letra maiúscula `:upper:`

Combinando esta expressão regular com a função `grep`, podemos encontrar os índices do vetor `ls()` que satisfazem nossa condição:

```
grep(pattern="[[:digit:]]|[[:upper:]]", ls())
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

Podemos buscar estes índices no vetor `ls()` original:

```
ls()[grep(pattern="[[:digit:]]|[[:upper:]]", ls())]
[1] "vector1"  "vector86" "vectorA"  "vectorU"
```

Finalmente, basta pegar o output acima e utilizá-lo na função `rm` para remover os objetos que não desejamos mais no workspace:

```
rm(list=ls()[grep(pattern="[[:digit:]]|[[:upper:]]", ls())])
ls()
[1] "vector"
```

---

Uma forma mais fácil de resolver o problema é utilizando a sugestão colocada nos comentários abaixo:

```
rm(grep(pattern="[[:digit:][:upper:]]", ls(), value = TRUE))
```

Comment: Mais simples? `grep(pattern="[[:digit:][:upper:]]", ls(), value = TRUE)`. Em vez da disjunção `|`, ter os padrões alternativos dentro dos `[]` dá o mesmo resultado. E em vez de duas chamadas à função `ls()`, `grep(..., value = TRUE)`.

Comment: Boa. Editei a minha resposta com esta sugestão.