# Remover elementos do Environment (e da lista) com base em suas classes

Tags: r

Considere os vetores:

```
a<-1:10
b<-1:10
c<-'a'
d<-'a'
e<-list('b')
f<-list('b')
g<-1.1
h<-1.1
```

A função abaixo remove apenas **uma** classe (que é `integer`, neste caso):

```
rm(list=names(Filter(is.integer,mget(ls()))))
```

Já tentei modificar esta função (ex. usar alguns operadores dentro dela para que fosse possível introduzir duas ou mais classes) mas até agora não consegui realizar esta ação.

Duas peguntas:

- como remover mais de uma classe (como por exemplo, `integer` e `list`) e deixar as outras no *environment*?
- como ficaria esta função caso eu jogasse todos os objetos em uma *lista* e, dentro dela, executasse a eliminação desses objetos com base nas classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baseado nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353137/43953), também é possível fazer assim (de maneira mais "[tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)"):

```
library(purrr)

remover <- ls() %>% 
  map(get) %>% 
  map(class) %>% 
  map_lgl(~.x %in% c("list",  "integer")) %>% 
  keep(.x = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))

rm(list = remover)

ls()
# [1] "c" "d" "g" "h"
```

As funções `get` e `ls` tem um argumento `envir` para saber "onde" realizar a busca. É possível passar um lista para este argumento para fazer a versão com listas.

Answer (score 5):

Chame uma função anônima dentro de `rm()` para não afetar os objetos mostrados em `ls()`.

```
a<-1:10
b<-1:10
c<-'a'
d<-'a'
e<-list('b')
f<-list('b')
g<-1.1
h<-1.1

rm(list = (function(x, types){

  envType <- sapply(x, function(x) {
    typeof(get(x)) # retorna um vetor (nomeado com o nome de cada objeto em ls()) com o tipo de cada objeto em ls()
  })

  out <- names(which(sapply(envType, function(x){
    any(x %in% types)
  }) == TRUE)) # retorna um vetor com os nomes dos objetos que obedecem a condição em "types".

  return(out)

})(ls(), c("list", "integer")) # observe que o argumento "type" é flexível
)
```

O que retorna:

```
> ls()
[1] "c" "d" "g" "h"
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma opção é usar a função `is()` que é mais genérica do que `is.integer`, por exemplo. Ela exige, como segundo argumento a classe que será verificada.

Colocar o resultado do `mget(ls())` proposto na pergunta dentro de uma lista pode ser útil para evitar ficar recriando a lista a cada iteração da função.

```
ambiente <- mget(ls())
```

Assim poderíamos ter uma função que retorne o nome dos objetos de uma lista que são de determinada classe.

```
filtrar_classe <- function(classe, lista) {
  names(Filter(function(x) is(x, classe), lista))
}
```

Uma vez definida a função, podemos aplicá-la às classes desejadas

```
classes <- c("list",  "integer") 

res <- classes %>% 
  lapply(filtrar_classe, lista = ambiente) %>% 
  unlist()
res
# [1] "e" "f" "a" "b"
```

Agora que temos um vetor de caracteres como resposta, podemos passar seu resultado como argumento para a função `rm()`.

```
rm(list = res)
ls()
# [1] "ambiente"       "c"              "classes"        "d"             
# [5] "filtrar_classe" "g"              "h"              "res"
```

### tidyverse

Se quisermos deixar a solução mais "tidy", podemos fazer como segue

```
filtrar_tidy <- function(classe, lista) {
  keep(lista, ~ is(.x, classe)) %>% 
    names()
}

classes %>% 
  map(filtrar_tidy, lista = ambiente) %>% 
  flatten_chr()
```

#### Sobre a opção na lista

A ideia é a mesma, basta usar os nomes em conjunto com `[` para selecionar os elementos da lista que deseja eliminar.

```
nova_lista <- ambiente[ !names(ambiente) %in% res ]
nova_lista
$c
[1] "a"   
$d
[1] "a"    
$g
[1] 1.1    
$h
[1] 1.1
```